# I am trying to commit files from my local directory to remote directory running on college git server

Tags: git

So the recently added files are in C:\xampp\htdocs\eatnow\doc\class_diagram\Final. I am trying to push the files inside this folder to remote directory. But I am getting this error message.

```
$ git push -u origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Girish/.ssh/id_rsa':
To mygit.th-deg.de:kf01580/EatNow.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@mygit.th-deg.de:kf01580/EatNow.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

After searching for solutions, I tried to pull it from remote repository, but again got an error message.

```
Girish@DESKTOP-AD4L93R MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/eatnow (master)
$ git pull origin doc --allow-unrelated-histories
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Girish/.ssh/id_rsa':
From mygit.th-deg.de:kf01580/EatNow
 * branch            doc        -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

You must pull branch `master`, not `doc`:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

Fix merge conflicts (if any), commit and push again:

```
git push -u origin master
```